# Do all black holes, including stellar-mass ones, rotate at nearly the speed of light? Also, what exactly does that do to their shape?

Tags: black-hole, astrophysics, supermassive-black-hole

From what I understand, astrophysicists have known for almost a decade that supermassive black holes seem to spin at incredible velocities; nearly the speed of light...  In fact, some of the outer particles being dragged around appear to be propelled to nearly seven times the speed of light c ....

Are intermediate-mass and stellar-mass black holes rotating like this?  Does anyone know yet?

Also, how much of an oblate spheroid is formed from this?  Are these super-Kerr black holes substantially wider than they are tall?  Can we tell from the images of M87's hole and our own (Sagittarius A*)?

Comment: Can you give citations for statements such as "particles ...seven times the speed of light" please.

Comment: I hope you mean "do particles outside the Swarszchild Radius" revolve at near-c speeds"  .

Answer (score 2):

If a black hole rotates, it decreases its Schwarzschild radius.

- Physics SE: [Why does angular momentum shorten the Schwarzschild Radius of a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121845/why-does-angular-momentum-shorten-the-schwarzschild-radius-of-a-black-hole#:%7E:text=Angular%20momentum%20causes%20the%20event,black%20hole%20wasn%27t%20spinning)
- Wikipedia: [Rotating black hole; Formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole#:%7E:text=In%20late%202006%2C%20astronomers%20reported,approaching%20the%20theoretical%20upper%20limit.)

are good resources to research more.

Stellar mass black holes have enormous rotations due to conservation of angular momentum. The star that made the black hole is already most likely spinning, and the black hole spins even faster since its compressed. We don't know how intermediate black holes form, but if they start from a star, then they would also be spinning rapidly.

Comment: There are measurements or estimates of stellar mass black hole spin parameters. Saying they are "enormous" doesn't really answer the main question.

Comment: The rotation of black holes vary depending on the velocity of the progenitor star. The fastest rotating black hole rotates 1,150 times per second. This black hole is GRS 1915+105